# why domain gpo wallpaper is getting applied to the desktops only after logoff or restart

Tags: group-policy, groups

I've appllied wallpaper to Win XP and Win7 PCs through group policy and it is getting applied to all these PCs. My problem is when I change wallpaper jpeg file in server, wallpaper is not automatically changing in client PCs for long time. New wall paper is displayed only after logging off or restart the PCs. I've set the grooup policy refresh interval as 30min. But still its not working. Other policies are working without logoff or restart.

Anyone have any advice. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Desktop wallpaper picture changed after explorer.exe restart only. 
Updating policy (refresh period doesn't metter) updates  path to wallpaper in client registry, not wallpaper picture itself. So relogon/restart it's only an option.

You can try remotely kill and restart explorer.exe - it should work. But take care about user account which will be used to restart explorer.exe (it can cause privilege elevation if runs under administrative account)

Comment: +1 An alternative would be to trigger [`SHChangeNotify`](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/WinXP/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/2006-03/msg09144.html) by a means other that restarting `explorer`.  Have a look at [this thread](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/WinXP/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/2006-03/msg09144.html). It suggests trying `RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` or using the supplied binary to perform the refresh.